# Live Feed from Java.exe to vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am trying to make a frontend for minecraft servers,

I am trying to get the feed from the java.exe into a text box. But When I do I get the first 2 lines of feed and then it just stops, Does anyone have any idea why?

```
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(txtServerLocation.Text + "\" + ServerFileName) Then

        frmDownloader.Show()
        wbcDownload.DownloadFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/minecraft_server.jar?", txtServerLocation.Text + "\" + ServerFileName)
        frmDownloader.Close()
    End If
    Me.txtConsole.Text = String.Empty
    Dim pi As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    With pi.StartInfo
        .FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .Arguments = "-Xmx" + nudAllocatedRam.Value.ToString + "M -Xms" + nudAllocatedRam.Value.ToString + "M -jar " + ServerFileName ' + " nogui"
    End With
    pi.Start()
    While (pi.HasExited = False)
        Dim sLine As String = pi.StandardOutput.ReadLine
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine)) Then
            Me.txtConsole.Text &= sLine & vbCrLf
        End If
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
```